# Creating a one-to-many TCP proxy using Netty

Tags: java, tcp, proxy, netty

I'm trying to create a TCP proxy that forwards request to many other TCP endpoints using Netty/Java.

For example:

```
                     /--> SERVER A 
Client A --> PROXY --
                     \--> SERVER B
```

If `Client A` sends a TCP command through the proxy, the proxy opens two TCP connections to `Server A` and `Server B`, and concurrently proxies the request sent by `Client A` to both of them.

If `Client A` subsequently sends another command, the proxy theoretically has previously cached the two connections in a pool, so without opening two new connections again, proxies the request to the two servers.

Regarding the response handling, I would like to have two options:

- Show two responses one after the other to `Client A`.
- Or completely ignore the response.

If a connection is lost or closed, the proxy should be able to automatically recreate it and add it back to the connection pool.

I've been looking at the Netty examples, and tried to use [`ChannelGroup`](http://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/channel/group/ChannelGroup.html) to handle the connection pool, but without success. Also, in my code below, after sending the first request the proxy stops working. Any tips?

```
import io.netty.bootstrap.Bootstrap;
import io.netty.buffer.Unpooled;
import io.netty.channel.Channel;
import io.netty.channel.ChannelFuture;
import io.netty.channel.ChannelFutureListener;
import io.netty.channel.ChannelHandlerContext;
import io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter;
import io.netty.channel.ChannelOption;
import io.netty.channel.group.ChannelGroup;
import io.netty.channel.group.DefaultChannelGroup;
import io.netty.util.concurrent.GlobalEventExecutor;

import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

public class TcpProxyHandler extends ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter {

    private static List<String> hosts = new LinkedList<>();
    private static List<String> connected = new LinkedList<>();

    static {
        hosts.add("127.0.0.1:10000");
        hosts.add("127.0.0.1:20000");
    }

    static final ChannelGroup channels = new DefaultChannelGroup(
            GlobalEventExecutor.INSTANCE);

    @Override
    public void channelActive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
        final Channel inboundChannel = ctx.channel();

        for (String host : hosts) {
            if (!connected.contains(host)) {
                String address = host.split(":")[0];
                int port = Integer.parseInt(host.split(":")[1]);
                Channel outboundChannel = ConnectionPool.getConnection(address,
                        port);
                if (outboundChannel == null) {
                    Bootstrap b = new Bootstrap();
                    b.group(inboundChannel.eventLoop())
                            .channel(ctx.channel().getClass())
                            .handler(new TcpProxyBackendHandler(inboundChannel))
                            .option(ChannelOption.AUTO_READ, false);
                    ChannelFuture f = b.connect(address, port);
                    outboundChannel = f.channel();
                    f.addListener(new ChannelFutureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void operationComplete(ChannelFuture future)
                                throws Exception {
                            if (future.isSuccess()) {
                                // connection complete start to read first data
                                inboundChannel.read();
                            } else {
                                // Close the connection if the connection
                                // attempt
                                // has failed.
                                inboundChannel.close();
                            }
                        }
                    });

                    channels.add(outboundChannel);
                    connected.add(host);
                    System.out.println("Connected to " + host);
                }
            }

        }

    }

    @Override
    public void channelRead(final ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg)
            throws Exception {
        channels.flushAndWrite(msg);
    }

    @Override
    public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Throwable cause)
            throws Exception {
        cause.printStackTrace();
        ctx.close();
    }

    static void closeOnFlush(Channel ch) {
        if (ch.isActive()) {
            ch.writeAndFlush(Unpooled.EMPTY_BUFFER).addListener(
                    ChannelFutureListener.CLOSE);
        }
    }

    static class TcpProxyBackendHandler extends ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter {

        private final Channel inboundChannel;

        public TcpProxyBackendHandler(Channel inboundChannel) {
            this.inboundChannel = inboundChannel;
        }

        @Override
        public void channelActive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
            ctx.read();
            ctx.write(Unpooled.EMPTY_BUFFER);
        }

        @Override
        public void channelRead(final ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg)
                throws Exception {
            inboundChannel.writeAndFlush(msg).addListener(
                    new ChannelFutureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void operationComplete(ChannelFuture future)
                                throws Exception {
                            if (future.isSuccess()) {
                                ctx.channel().read();
                            } else {
                                future.channel().close();
                            }
                        }
                    });
        }

        @Override
        public void channelInactive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
            TcpProxyHandler.closeOnFlush(inboundChannel);
        }

        @Override
        public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Throwable cause)
                throws Exception {
            cause.printStackTrace();
            TcpProxyHandler.closeOnFlush(ctx.channel());
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Can I ask what use case this model serves? Just curious...

Comment: @Santa I'm personally trying to create an eventually consistent replication model across many Redis instances. This means that, for example, by sending "INCR counter" to the proxy, the command will be propagated to all the Redis instances (and eventually all of them will have the "counter" key incremented). I can see other scenarios where such TCP proxy could be useful.

Comment: What's the actual question?

Comment: @EJP I've updated the question with my code (the handler) which doesn't work. I'm looking for some help to make it work.

Comment: @Mark, could you find any solution? I have the exact similar scenario, and I am not being able to make it work. Basically the non blocking connection to the destination host doesn't complete. And if I try to use a blocking mode, it gives an exception since I am not allowed to do blocking IO from a handler.

Comment: @Mark- I have a similar problem scenario as well, do you guys have a solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to call connect() and read() in another thread to give a chance to ChannelGrop's worker to do its work.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't tried yet, enable AUTO_READ again and remove the manual invokations to read(). You may initialize your server also with auto read set to false, you could try to change this too.